# Can't recover account even though I see the email address on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

I'm logged in to Stack Overflow. I click my user name, I click "my logins", it shows 2 accounts.

1. an OpenID account.
2. an email address.

My OpenID provider is broken. I tried what I thought would be the password for my email based account but no luck. I open a new browser and try to recover the password typing in the email address from #2, but Stack Overflow says no such account exists. It's the exact same email address shown as for the account in #2 above.

Is this a bug in Stack Overflow?

PS: It's **not** the account leaving this message. I added this account hoping I could add it to "my logins" into the other account but that feature is also apparently broken.

Comment: And your openID provider is...

Comment: Myself using phpMyId which no longer works since my ISP upgraded php to something that phpMyId no longer supports